# laravel - CKEditor not showing up

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

I have little problem. I tried to add CKEditor to my textarea fields, but..but it is not showing up. I got only white space instead field.
So, here's screenshot:

[image]

Here's my textarea field:

```
{{ Form::textarea('other_details', '', array('class'=>'form-control other_details', 'placeholder'=>trans('event.additional'))) }}
```

How I added ckeeditor's .js file:

```
{{ HTML::script('js/ckeditor.js') }}
```

And now how I call script in my custom .js file:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('other_details');
```

Comment: I think ckeditor creates a div, and hides your textarea check with inspect element.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using laravel 4.

Comment: Got an answer. Solution is in comment under 1st answer.